# How to write avi file from sequence of TBitmaps?

Tags: delphi

I found a way to write avi from BMP files: 
http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_2770.asp?SK=

I want to write avi from array or TList of TBitmaps?

Comment: Does FireFox tell anybody else that delphi3000 is "als attackierend gemeldet" (reported as attacking?

Comment: Yes, it reports it as an attacking site, I don't know why tho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key portion of the code you linked to is below, where `IList` is a `TStrings` with the names of all the files to include in the animation.

```
for i := 0 to IList.Count - 1 do begin
  AssignFile(BFile, IList[i]);
  Reset(BFile, 1);
  Seek(BFile, m_bfh.bfOffBits);
  BlockRead(BFile, m_MemBits[0], m_Bih.biSizeImage);
  Seek(BFile, SizeOf(m_Bfh));
  BlockRead(BFile, m_MemBitMapInfo[0], length(m_MemBitMapInfo));
  CloseFile(BFile);
  if AVIStreamWrite(psCompressed, i, 1, @m_MemBits[0],
      m_Bih.biSizeImage, AVIIF_KEYFRAME, 0, 0) <> 0 then begin
    ShowMessage('Error during Write AVI File');
    break;
  end;
end;
```

It reads portions of the file from disk and writes them to the AVI stream. The important part is that it reads from the *files*. The in-memory representation of a `TBitmap` doesn't necessarily match with the representation of a file. However, it's easy to adapt the given code to temporarily store the bitmaps in a memory stream; the stream will match what the layout of the file would be. Suppose `IList` is now an array of `TBitmap`, as you suggested. Then we could use this:

```
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;

ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  for i := 0 to Length(IList) - 1 do begin
    IList[i].SaveToStream(ms);
    ms.Position := m_bfh.bfOffBits;
    ms.ReadBuffer(m_MemBits[0], m_Bih.biSizeImage);
    ms.Position := SizeOf(m_Bfh);
    ms.ReadBuffer(m_MemBitMapInfo[0], Length(m_MemBitMapInfo));
    ms.Clear;
    if AVIStreamWrite(psCompressed, i, 1, @m_MemBits[0],
        m_Bih.biSizeImage, AVIIF_KEYFRAME, 0, 0) <> 0 then begin
      ShowMessage('Error during Write AVI File');
      break;
    end;
  end;
finally
  ms.Free;
end;
```

There's code earlier in your cited example that reads the first file in the list to populate the various records and size the arrays used here, but you should be able to make the same changes there as I have done to the code shown here.

Comment: It would be nice if you paste the whole example and change the necessary parts and definitely this will be my accepted answer.

Comment: No, Isa, I'd prefer not to. Which additional part of the code are you having trouble with? Do you recognize what changes I made in the above passages? Do you understand what they're for? Don't copy and paste code into your project if you don't understand what it does, because even though you didn't write it, since it's in your project you're going to have to support it eventually.

Comment: I understand -in general- what is going on in the cited example
And I thought about storing the bitmaps in memory stream before asking this question 
But I couldn’t write it correctly. still can’t write it correctly  
I get access violation error.
And no, no body will ask me to support my code I’m coding this for fun.
Anyway thank you for your help and advice :-)